# What is a learning agreement used for and when it is necessary

Tags: learning, contract, student-exchange

I am going to be at a university as an exchange student. I will not take any courses and will work with a professor. There is an online application form which asks me to upload a learning agreement and the website of the university provides a suggested template for it. Also, I have searched about what this agreement is through many sources.

It seems that this "learning agreement" is for those people who are going to take courses in a university other than their home university. Am I right?

If my assumption is true, does it mean that I do not have to upload this kind of agreement?

Comment: I think you'll have to ask someone involved at the university you will be an exchange student at, there won't be a general answer to give here.

Comment: I wanted to do that. But the deadline is the day after tomorrow, and the university's incoming mobility office is closed tomorrow. Anyway, I do not want an exact answer. Just share your experiences.

Comment: Why have you waited so long?

Comment: @BryanKrause Long story short, I have not. There was a problem with their online application form, and they just fixed it today.

Comment: Never heard of such a thing - might help to mention what region/country the University is in. Is the term given in English, or is this a translation? If this were the US I would say that there is no standard such thing, so only people familiar with that particular and peculiar instrument at that University can provide guidance. But perhaps this a more common thing in some countries?

Answer (score 1):

As the comments have mentioned, this is not a standard thing. It's possible the university doesn't even have a standard learning agreement, although it might.

> It seems that this "learning agreement" is for those people who are going to take courses in a university other than their home university. Am I right?

It's not strictly for exchange students. A local student doing something similar would probably have to do one too. Basically, for "independent study" courses where you aren't taking a class, and are working one-on-one with a professor, it outlines the expectations and grading criteria for you, in lieu of a syllabus.

Especially because you are coming from a different county, they don't want you to a) show up and not have a productive experience because your goals aren't well defined; and b) they don't want any fraud occurring, after all, they are sponsoring you for a visa (presumably).

Unfortunately, I find it unlikely you and your sponsor can prepare this in a day or two.

Comment: I would modify the last sentence: In the absence of detailed instructions, the only thing you _can_ do is write up something that you and you sponsor agree looks reasonable, and submit that. If it works, great! If it doesn’t, there’s nothing else you could have done.

Comment: @JeffE I meant more, it seems unlikely two people could prepare one from scratch in 24-36 hours, especially with how busy professors are and a possible time zone difference.